# How to install H2O in Anaconda R-essentials?

Tags: r, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, h2o

I am using Jupyter notebooks with R i.e. by using R-essentials in Anaconda.
However, while installing H2O package in Jupyter notebook using

> install.packages("h2o")

it is giving an error and unable to install it. I also tried

> conda install c -r anaconda h20

in terminal and it did installed h2o. But while exceuting the library function in the r notebook:

> library(h2o)

I am getting the following error message:

```
Error in library(h2o): there is no package called ‘h2o’
Traceback:

1. library(h2o)
2. stop(txt, domain = NA)
```

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install h2o from within R please follow the download instructions [here](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-xu/6/index.html) (this link will provide you with the latest stable version). 
for your convenience I am also pasting what is currently listed under the R tab (below):

Please also note that it looks like you ran `h20` instead of `h2o` (like water) in `conda install c -r anaconda h20` and in addition looking at the [anaconda docs](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/r-language-pkg-docs/) if you want to install an r package you need to pre-fix the package with an `r-`, and lastly if you want to install h2o from anaconda you should use the `h2oai` channel not the default anaconda channel. That being said if you do a search for the `r-h2o` package you will see if is not available for download in this manner `conda search -f r-h2o` so your best option is to install through R via the instructions pasted below.

```
Copy and paste these commands into R one line at a time:

# The following two commands remove any previously installed H2O packages for R.
if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload=TRUE) }
if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) { remove.packages("h2o") }

# Next, we download packages that H2O depends on.
pkgs <- c("RCurl","jsonlite")
for (pkg in pkgs) {
if (! (pkg %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages(pkg) }
}

# Now we download, install and initialize the H2O package for R.
install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos="http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-xu/6/R")

# Finally, let's load H2O and start up an H2O cluster
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
```

Comment: Yes I have done that and I am able to use h2o using R and R studio. I just wanted to use h2o in Jupyter notebooks (with R backend) as well but that is not happening as it is not able to see the installed package.